# Gestures not getting registered

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a Pan and Tap gestures, They don't seem to get recognized when I try to activate them on the simulator.
I don't get any error, tried to debugging, it seems that it does assign the gestures, but won't call the methods I try to use when they happened, like it just don't recognize them at all.
This is what I have:

```
dismissIndicator: (Attaching the Pan recognizer to this view):
    let dismissIndicator: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.appWhite
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

        let dismissImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "closeArrow"))
        dismissImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(dismissImg)

        dismissImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissImg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        return view
    }()
```

This is how I set the gestures:

```
let dimView = UIView()
let detailView = DetailsView()
var currentPost: Post? = nil

init(post: Post) {
    super.init()

    dimView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

    let panGesture = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .vertical(.down), target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerHandler(_:)))

    detailView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    setPostDetails(post: post)
}
```

This is handleDismiss (Which does not get called when tapping on the DimView:

```
@objc func handleDismiss(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.dimView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow  {
            self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.detailView.frame.width, height: self.detailView.frame.height)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my panGestureRecognizerHandler:

```
@objc func panGestureRecognizerHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: detailView.dismissIndicator.window)
    var initialTouchPoint = CGPoint.zero

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        initialTouchPoint = touchPoint
    case .changed:
        if touchPoint.y > initialTouchPoint.y {
            detailView.frame.origin.y = initialTouchPoint.y + touchPoint.y
        }
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > 300 {
            handleDismiss()
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                    let height = window.frame.height - 80
                    let y = window.frame.height - height

                    self.dimView.alpha = 1
                    self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.detailView.frame.width, height: self.detailView.frame.height)
                }
            })
        }
    case .failed, .possible:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This is where I add dimView and detailView to the screen:

```
    func showDetailView(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        dimView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        window.addSubview(dimView)
        window.addSubview(detailView)

        let height = window.frame.height - 80
        let y = window.frame.height - height // This is so we can later slide detailView all the way down.

        detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

        dimView.frame = window.frame
        dimView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.dimView.alpha = 1
            self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.detailView.frame.width, height: self.detailView.frame.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `let dimView = UIView()` creates an empty view with no width or height. Do you later add that view to a parent view? Do you give it a non-empty frame anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I have a method that adds it to the screen and giving it a frame. I also have this same gestures in another screen in my app, and they work there. I put a break point and it seems that they do get the gestures, but don't call them when they happen.

Comment: When and where are you adding `dismissIndicator` and `dimView` to the view hierarchy?

Comment: @PankajKulkarni dismissIndicator is part of DetailView, it is the first thing getting added to thet View. dimView  (and detailView) are getting added in another function I have in postDetail. I will add the function to the OP.

Comment: Please post a downloadable project.

Comment: Have you enabled user interaction on the view ?

Comment: Yes. I really can’t see where the problem is :/